# Adding Layer on Top of Another Layer in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've a `UIViewController` which has the default plain view. I've added a `UIImageView` at the top of the parent view. Now, I want to display the PulsingHaloLayer on top of the UIImageView.

**I have been following this url** https://github.com/shu223/PulsingHalo

**And have the following code:**

```
PulsingHaloLayer *halo = [PulsingHaloLayer layer];
halo.position = self.imageView.center; // image view is an image of radar
        // frame = (0,0; 240 128)

[self.imageView.layer addSublayer:halo]; // displays nothing
```

**I also tried the following with no luck:**

```
 PulsingHaloLayer *halo = [PulsingHaloLayer layer];
 halo.position = self.imageView.center; // image view is an image of radar
 // frame = (0,0; 240 128)
 [self.view.layer insertSublayer:halo above:self.imageView.layer]; // nothing
```

Comment: Can you try the same code, adding just a regular layer with a background color rather than the pulsing halo layer. That'd give you confidence in your layer adding and focus the question on what makes pulsing halo layer different

Comment: Only thing that looks different in their sample app is setting the initial radius of the halo

Comment: Can you please try `[self.imageView.layer insertSublayer:halo atIndex:0];`

Comment: Thanks! But even adding at the imageView index 0 does not make it appear. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are missing `[halo start];`.When i try demo from the link you provided, the layer was not added untill I add `[halo start];`. The code you have provided does not contain `[halo start];` too.